# How to debug and view IndexedDB Usage for a Website in Safari DevTools

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, indexeddb

I'm working on a PWA and need to monitor the storage usage for my website, including resources cached using the "Offline Cache API." I'm using Safari as my browser, and I'm having difficulty finding a way to access detailed storage information in Safari DevTools which I have connected via my Mac running Safari developer options to my iPhone. I have run into these limitations many times before, but now just looking for a clean way to debug this or any pro tips as webkit debugging is very limited.

Here are my specific questions and concerns:

1. I am noticing limitations on IndexedDB it seems to have limited storage space on iOS mobile, how can I view the space used and space remaining for IndexedDB what are the known issues here?
2. Resource Consumption: I want to understand how much storage my website is using, including the sizes of various storage-related resources. Is there a way to access detailed information about the storage consumption of these resources in Safari DevTools?
3. Advanced Debugging: Are there any advanced techniques or approaches to monitor storage usage for a website in Safari DevTools, especially for resources cached using the "Offline Cache API"?

Thank you for your help!